# Error message 1 in "subprocess.py", any recommendations on what to do next?

Tags: python, tor

getting this error message after i run the file that is supposed to connect the browser

```
  File "C:\Users\A\Documents\dw_pipeline_test\MarketPlaces\Initialization\markets_mining.py", line 79, in <module>
    opentor()
  File "C:\Users\A\Documents\dw_pipeline_test\MarketPlaces\Initialization\markets_mining.py", line 70, in opentor
    pro = subprocess.Popen(config.get('TOR', 'firefox_binary_path'))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\A\Documents\Anaconda\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\A\Documents\Anaconda\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i tried going through my own code not sure if my Anaconda interpreter has to do with the issue,
never used `firefox_binary` or selenium before so generally pretty inexperienced. thank you for any help

```
def opentor():
    global pid
    print("Connecting Tor...")
    pro = subprocess.Popen(config.get('TOR', 'firefox_binary_path'))
    pid = pro.pid
    # time.sleep(7.5)
    input('Press ENTER when Tor is connected to continue')
    return
```

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Please post the full code, and the full error traceback message, as plain text.

Comment: What is the output of `config.get("TOR", "firefox_binary_path")` ?

Comment: @JohnGordon i have made edits to the post! thank you for letting me know, first time posting on here.

Comment: it seems it gives you wrong value from `config.get()` - and first you could use `print()` to check what you get. It may need to use `/full/path/to/firefox.exe` instead of `'firefox_binary_path'`. Or it may need to set `/full/path/to/tor.exe` in `config`

Comment: @furas , i did try that and i get the same error messages... the error is coming from the subprocess itself i guess

Comment: did you check what you get from `config.get("TOR", "firefox_binary_path")`? Get this result and try to run it directly in shell/terminal. If it can't work in sell/terminal then it can't work in `subprocess`. And it may need to find full path to execute program and use this fuil path in `subprocess` because it may run with different settings than shell/terminal and it may doesn't know where to search this program.

Comment: `config.get('TOR', 'firefox_binary_path')` If it can't find `TOR` in the config, then it will fall back to using the _literal string_ "firefox_binary_path".  Surely that is not what you meant?  Did you have a _variable_ by that name?